# Rotate element so its pointing to a specific point in space

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having problems with rotating an element (BoxVisual3D).

We have two spheres. The first one is red, the second one is blue. There is a box element with the same center point as the second sphere.

What I need at this point is to rotate this box visual so that its pointing to the red dot. They are all in the same coordinate system. I've done various calculations, but none of them worked the way I wanted. The objective is to find an universal rotation solution.

A short snippet for element rotation around one of the axis.

```
RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), RotX));
myRotateTransform.CenterX = Spheres[1].Center.X;
myRotateTransform.CenterY = Spheres[1].Center.Y;
myRotateTransform.CenterZ = Spheres[1].Center.Z;

Transform3DGroup RotGroup = new Transform3DGroup();
RotGroup.Children.Add(myRotateTransform);

Models[0].Transform = RotGroup;
```

Thanks guys!

Edit:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMw1RV8LbIQ) Done.

Comment: You need to calculate two angles.  First the rotation in the X-Y plane.  Then the rotation in the Z plane.  The X-Y angle is arcTan(Y2-Y1, X2-X1).  The Z angle you have two sides of a triangle.  The hypotenuse which is the distance of line [sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)] and the Z height [z2-z1].  So 2nd angle is arcSin(Z-height/distance).

Comment: The right eye opener I needed. 

float anglez = (float)(Math.Atan(mVector.Y / mVector.X) * (180 / Math.PI));
float angley = (float)(Math.Asin(mVector.Z / mVector.Length) * (180 / Math.PI));

Worked like a charm. Thanks mate.

Comment: I got an A++ in high school Geometry.  Still remember most of the basics.  In college had linear algebra.  Learn 3-D x,y,z in three different classes in the same week : Math, Physics, Mechanics.